# Installing Eclipse Neon error

Tags: eclipse, installation, eclipse-neon

I am installing Eclipse error and I am getting this error

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927
... 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy
```

org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927
```

I have set "Path" in System variables as "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.1\bin"
and "CLASSPATH" in System Variables as "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin"

Comment: Why an old version of Eclipse but the newest Java? You should be using Oxygen.3a.

Comment: If you want to use Java 10 you should be installing Eclipse Oxygen.3a

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hi,**

**Add this lines at end of your eclipse.ini**

```
--add-modules=java.se.ee
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you're version of Eclipse and JDK match, either both
    64-bit or both 32-bit, then set the path of the JRE in the
    environment .

Comment: I was having Eclipse Neon + JDK 8. After my JDK got updated to 11, Eclipse failed opening up.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [@RaghuPrasanth V](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50404045/8370915) and [@nitind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50404009/installing-eclipse-neon-error#comment87824080_50404009), be sure that your version of Eclipse is working with newer versions of Java.

Because I had the same issue:

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
```

using *`Java 11`* and *`Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0) Build id: 20170620-1800`*

And to solve it, I have re-installed to:

*`Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers. Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0) Build id: 20190314-1200`*  from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/).